# C# ViewComponent

Tags: c#, view

I have the GreeterViewComponent.

```
public class GreeterViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        public GreeterViewComponent()
        {

        }
        public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
        {
            return View("Default");
        }
    }
```

how can I open the ViewComponent using tag :

```
<a href=""></a>
```

thank you & regards.,

Answer (score 0):

Your question about using an anchor tag (`<a></a>`) is a little ambigious, so I'll answer both possibilities.

#### 1. You want to reach your ViewComponent by an endpoint (URL)

According to this [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

ViewComponents are designed to be invoked from a view

> ViewComponents are not reachable directly as an HTTP endpoint, they're invoked from your code (usually in a view). A view component never handles a request.
>
> While view components don't define endpoints like controllers, you can easily implement a controller action that returns the content of a ViewComponentResult.

#### 2. You want to use a different syntax to invoke the ViewComponent

ViewComponents can be invoked in 2 ways. The first using `@Component.Invoke("ComponentName")`

The second is by the [ViewComponent Tag Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.2) which roughly is used like

```
<vc:[view-component-name]
  parameter1="parameter1 value"
  parameter2="parameter2 value">
</vc:[view-component-name]>
```